# Negative gap statistic interpretation for cluster analysis

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to perform a cluster analysis on a dataset. The plot of clusters vs. gap statistic is below. I do not know how to interpret the decrease of the gap statistic and its values which are negative. Therefore, I have no idea about how many clusters can I choose then based on this figure for an optimal clustering?

Could someone help please ?

[image]

Comment: The figure helpfully tells you where the optimum is.

Comment: @whuber But what does a negative gap statistic mean ? And what about if I really need to have more than one cluster of my data?

Comment: Because the gap statistic is based on a *logarithm,* there is little inherent meaning to its sign.  You are meant to *compare* statistics for different numbers of clusters, not to hold them up to some fixed standard or threshold.